# How to keep Rows and Columns headers when applying operation using Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a data set stored in an excel file, when i importing data using matlab function :

```
A=xlread(xls -filename)
```

matrix A only stored numeric values of my table.. and when i used another function such as:

```
B= readtable(xls-filename)
```

then table will view complete data include rows and columns headers but when i apply such operation on it like

```
Bnorm=normc(B)
```

its unable to perform normalization on it due to the rows and columns headers ..

**my question are:**

- is there any way to avoid rows and columns header in table B.
- is there any way to store rows and columns headers when read table using xlread function .. such that 
  column header = store first row in (xls-filename) 
  row headers = store first column in (xls-filename)

thanks for any suggestion

[dataset table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMhKc.png)

[normalized matrix when apply xlread(xls-filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NuGL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your specific questions are:

- With a table, you can avoid row labels but column labels always exist.
- As per the doc for [xlsread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html), the first output is the numeric data, and the second output is the text data, which in this case would include your header information.

But, in this case, you just need to learn how to work with tables properly.  You want something like,

```
>> Bnorm = normc(B{:,2:end});
```

which extracts all the numeric elements of table `B` and uses them as input to `normc`.

If you want the result to be a table then use

```
Bnorm = B;
Bnorm{:,2:end} = normc(B{:,2:end}));
```

Comment: this code give me an error : Cannot concatenate the table variables 'wet' and 'inst', because their types are double and cell

Comment: Based on the image of your table, I have updated the answer to reflect just getting the numeric elements of `B` (assuming only the first column of B is non-numeric).